# Django URL white space Issue

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have just installed **Django 1.10.3** and have made a project with application called **profiles**.

I have added a url `url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),` in **my_site/urls.py**

and in **profiles/urls.py** I have added:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'create^$', views.create_profile, name='create_profile'),
]
```

but on my web page I get this:
`^profiles/ create^$ [name='create_profile']`
due to which I can not get into my webpage. Please help me out.

I can't see webpage by either of these urls:

```
http://localhost:8000/profiles/create

http://localhost:8000/profiles/ create
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is messed up. You have: `r'create^$'`. Remove the `^`.

Comment: ya ^ should be at beginning :)

Comment: @MHS if that fixed your problem can you accept this?